# how to resolve initiating errors while running scripts with Rustscan Scripting Engine?

Tags: nmap, rust

I wrote a one-liner shell script for `rustscan` which runs `gobuster` if port 80 is open.
I have added the script to `/home/$USER/.rustscan_scripts` directory.

The script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
#tags=["first","second"]
#developer=[ "example","http://sdf.com" ]
#trigger_port= "80"
#call_format = "bash {{script}} {{ip}} {{port}}"

gobuster -u {{ip}} -w /usr/share/wordlists/rockyou.txt -t 50 -o gobus.txt
```

And the error I got was this:

```
[!] Initiating scripts failed!
No such file or directory (os error 2)
```

I tried a sample python3 script too which was there in docs but got the same error.

Comment: Instead of `{{ip}}` you should have `$1` in your `gobuster` inovocation.  And you might try using an absolute path for gobuster (e.g. `/home/gaurav/bin/gobuster` or whatever).  If those don't help it's a rustscan issue...

Comment: Then I think it's a rustscan issue because I have already tired with $1 and full path.